# Symfony 2 - Retrieve Entity with Json, return another Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, json

I have a problem while json_encodeing a Entity.

```
public function jsonvoteAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('KorumAGBundle:AGVote')->findOneById($id);
    $response = new Response(json_encode($entity, 200));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type',' application/json');
    return $response;
    }
```

This code returns me a the users entity

```
 {"users":{"__isInitialized__":false,"id":null,"nickname":null,"pwd":null,"email":null,"firstname":null,"lastname":null,"poste":null,"addr1":null,"addr2":null,"pc":null,"country":null,"phone":null,"province":null,"acess":null,"site":null,"crew":null,"utilisateur":null}}
```

And when I var dymp my $entity, it returns both my AGVote and USers entity.

Here is my AGVote Entity

```
    <?php
    namespace Korum\AGBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Korum\AGBundle\Entity\AGVote
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
     */
    class AGVote
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * 
         */
        private $id;

         /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        private $question;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
         */
        private $actif;

         /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Korum\KBundle\Entity\Users", cascade={"all"})
         */
        public $users;

   /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set question
     * Nb : Only AG admin can set a question
     * @param text $question
     */
    public function setQuestion($question)
    {
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return text 
     */
    public function getquestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * Set actif
     *
     * @param smallint $actif
     */
    public function setActif($actif)
    {
        $this->actif = $actif;
    }

    /**
     * Get actif
     *
     * @return smallint
     */
    public function getActif()
    {
        return $this->actif;
    }

     /**
     * Set Users
     *
     * @param Korum\KBundle\Entity\Province $Users
     */
    public function setUsers(\Korum\KBundle\Entity\Users $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
     * Get Users
     *
     * @return Korum\KBundle\Entity\Users
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what happened ?

---

I tried to install the JSMSerializerBundle but event with Metadata library at version 1.1.
When I want to clear my cache, it failed with error :

See : 
[JMSSerializerBundle Installation : Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to JMSSerializerBundle\Twig\SerializerExtension::__construct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075247/jmsserializerbundle-installation-catchable-fatal-error-argument-1-passed-to-j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `json_encode` only uses public properties.
So it serialized the only public property of `AGVote`: `$users`. The content of `$users` was an instance of `User`; which public fields were serialized.

You could work around these by adding a toArray() method to your entities, and then doing `json_encode($entity->toArray())`, but i highly recommend you to have a look and use the **[JMSSerializedBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle)**.

Comment: Ok, it make sense to me ;)
So I've got to put everything in public for json_encode all of my properties ... But it could make some security breach 
JMSSerialzed Bundle did it more securely (don't need to put my properties in public too ?) ?

Comment: With JMSSerializeBundle, you don't have to change your model, you only have to add metadata (Annotations, yaml files ...). Additionally, JMSSerializeBundle allows to define exclusion policy to only serialize wanted properties, and you can even define different groups like with the Symfony Validator component.