# JMSSerializerBundle Installation : Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to JMSSerializerBundle\Twig\SerializerExtension::__construct()

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to install the JSMSerializerBundle but event with Metadata library at version 1.1.
When I want to clear my cache, it failed with error :

> [ErrorException]
>   Catchable Fatal Error:
>   Argument 1 passed to `JMS\SerializerBundle\Twig\SerializerExtension::__construct()` must be an instance of `JMS\SerializerBundle\Serializer\SerializerInterface`, instance of `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer` given,
>
> called in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Korum/app/cache/dev_new/appDevDebugProjectContainer__5033ecec2dcbc__.php` on line 2397 and defined in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/K/vendor/bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle/Twig/SerializerExtension.php` line 37

In fact, the `AppKernel` code seems strange to me with the `$this`:

```php
// in AppKernel::registerBundles()
$bundles = array(
    // ...
    new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
    // ...
);
```

Do you have this error too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem.

It was a problem of configuration in config.yml linked to a problem of unregistered Bundle in AppKernel.